# Special grid layout with tailwindcss

Tags: css, css-grid, tailwind-css

I'd like to create this kind of layout:

[Layout wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5lIK.png)

I want to use the popular utility css framework "Tailwindcss" to achieve that. Does anybody know how to proceed? Any direction would help me.

I'm sure this kind of structure is possible but I can't find anything around.

Also, the data are pulled out a database and arrive in the number order as in the picture.

Thanks so much in advance for your time!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since Feb 2020 and Tailwind CSS v1.2 it became ridiculously easy to  do this task :)

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-4 grid-rows-3">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div class="row-span-2 col-span-2">3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
</div>
```

cool eh?

**Update 2023**

Still works fine: https://play.tailwindcss.com/q4RB94MPb8

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that Result using `css grid` only, since "Tailwindcss" works based on `display: flex`, it will be really hard to achieve that using it. please have a look at the below working snippet, hope it helps :)

```css
.item1 { grid-area: a1; }
.item2 { grid-area: a2; }
.item3 { grid-area: a3; }
.item4 { grid-area: a4; }
.item5 { grid-area: a5; }
.item6 { grid-area: a6; }
.item7 { grid-area: a7; }
.item8 { grid-area: a8; }
.item9 { grid-area: a9; }

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    'a1 a2 a3 a3'
    'a4 a5 a3 a3'
    'a6 a7 a8 a9';
}

/* Additional styling */
.grid-container > div {
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.grid-container {
  grid-gap: 1px;
  background-color: #000;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 1px;
}
.item3 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">1</div>
  <div class="item2">2</div>
  <div class="item3">3</div>
  <div class="item4">4</div>
  <div class="item5">5</div>
  <div class="item6">6</div>
  <div class="item7">7</div>
  <div class="item8">8</div>
  <div class="item9">9</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This [plugin for grid areas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@savvywombat/tailwindcss-grid-areas) lets you define grid areas in your TailwindCSS config and creates utilities to then place elements where you want them in the grid:

```
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  purge: {
    content: [
      './src/**/*.html',
    ],
  },
  theme: {
    extend: {
      gridTemplateAreas: {
        'default': [
          '.    .    hero hero',
          '.    .    hero hero',
          '.    .    .    .',
        ]
      },
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    require('../tailwindcss-grid-areas'),
  ],
}
```

```
<div class="lg:grid grid-areas-default grid-cols-4 w-full h-64">
    <div class="grid-in-hero">3 (Hero)</div>

    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
    <div>9</div>
</div>
```

On screens larger than the 'lg' breakpoint (the default TailwindCSS value is 1024 px), the layout will look like the grid you wanted.

On smaller screens (you can use a different breakpoint if you want, or none at all, but there is likely to be a minimum width before your layout becomes a bit squashed with the 4 columns you want), the content will just be displayed in DOM order using default block layout rules. Assuming your larger hero content is more important than the rest, you will want this to  render above the other.

DOM order is also relevant for people using accessible technology like screen-readers.